# SQLite3 auto increment value of the last updated item

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I created my own SQLite3 library and it works fine.

Now I have some trouble finding out the auto increment values of entries.

My entry has an auto_increment value called id, it is not set until I upload the entry.

How do I get directly after uploading the auto_increment value SQLite3 does assign to my uploaded entries?

Yours,

Joern

Answer (score 0):

In the C API, the ID of the last inserted record is returned by the [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).
Your library should call that.